# Check iPhone network settings - Enable 3G

Tags: ios4

I want to know if I can connect to the internet with 3G - before trying to establish a connection.

Is there some API which can tell me of the "Enable 3G" option in network settings is "ON" or "OFF"

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after? [Reachability sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)